# Nested CASE Statement With ELSe (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a CASE statement something like following

```
CASE 
       WHEN A IS NULL 
       THEN CASE
                 WHEN B IN ('C','D') THEN NULL
                 WHEN X NOT IN ('C','D') THEN Z
                 End
                 ELSE SOMETHING_ELSE -- Want to get here When 'A' IS NOT NULL
                 END AS 'Result'
```

I want to get to ELSE part when First CASE is not true i-e 'A' is not NULL. Can anyone suggest if i have wrongly nested them? not getting results right.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you don't need to nest `case` statements.  Just use one case:

```
select (CASE WHEN A IS NULL AND B IN ('C', 'D') THEN NULL
             WHEN A IS NULL AND X NOT IN ('C','D') THEN Z
             WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN SOMETHING_ELSE
        END) as Result
```

Note that when `A IS NULL` but the first two conditions are *not* met, then the return value will be `NULL`.

Because `case` statements are evaluated sequentially, this is simpler to write as:

```
select (CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN SOMETHING_ELSE
             WHEN B IN ('C', 'D') THEN NULL
             WHEN X NOT IN ('C', 'D') THEN Z
        END) as Result
```

The first condition captures when `A` is not `NULL`. Hence the second two are when `A` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 8):

You can add the second When to your case where you can check for the second condition and set value otherwise set default value.

```
CASE 
    WHEN A IS NULL THEN CASE
                          WHEN B IN ('C','D') THEN NULL
                          WHEN X NOT IN ('C','D') THEN Z
                        End
    WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN yourdesiredvalue
    ELSE default value
    END AS 'Result'
```

Comment: Will it give me Result even if frist CASE is true

Comment: How it is possible that that `A` is both `NULL` and `NOT NULL` at same time.??